# Conditions for the disintegration theorem to hold

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

[The disintegration theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disintegration_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) says that under certain conditions, a probability measure $\mu$ on a measurable space $$ the existence of

> Let $Y$ and $X$ be two Radon spaces (i.e. separable
>   metric spaces on which every probability measure is a Radon measure).
>   Let $μ ∈ P(Y)$, let $π : Y → X$ be a Borel-measurable function, and
>   let $ν ∈ P(X)$ be the pushforward measure from $Y$ to $X$ by $π$. Then
>   there exists a $ν$-almost everywhere uniquely determined family of
>   probability measures $\{μ_x\}_{x∈X} ⊆ P(Y)$ such that
>
> - the function $x \mapsto \mu_{x}$ is Borel measurable, in the sense    that $x \mapsto \mu_{x} (B)$ is a Borel-measurable function for each
>     Borel-measurable set $B ⊆ Y$;
> - $μ_x$ lives on the fiber $π^{-1}(x)$: for $ν$-almost all $x ∈ X$, $$\mu_{x} \left( Y \setminus \pi^{-1} (x) \right) = 0,$$ and so
>     $\mu_x(E) = \mu_x(E \cap \pi^{-1}(x));$
> - for every Borel-measurable function $f : Y → [0, +∞]$,
>        $$\int_{Y} f(y) \, \mathrm{d} \mu (y) = \int_{X} \int_{\pi^{-1} (x)}    f(y) \, \mathrm{d} \mu_{x} (y) \mathrm{d} \nu (x).$$

1. I was wondering if the probability measures can be relaxed to
   measures in the disintegration theorem?
2. [when $Y = X_1 × X_2$ and $π_i : Y → X_i$ is the natural
   projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disintegration_theorem#Product_spaces), we can apply the disintegration theorem, and get the
   result

   > each fibre $π_1^{-1}(x1)$ can be canonically identified with $X_2$ and
   >   there exists a Borel family of probability measures $\{ \mu_{x_{1}}  \}_{x_{1} \in X_{1}}$ in $P(X_2)$ (which is
   >   $(π_1)∗(μ)$-almost
   >   everywhere uniquely determined) such that $$  \mu = \int_{X_{1}} \mu_{x_{1}} \, \mu \left(\pi_1^{-1}(\mathrm d x_1) \right)=
   >     \int_{X_{1}} \mu_{x_{1}} \, \mathrm{d} (\pi_{1})_{*}  (\mu) (x_{1}),
   >     $$

   I wonder if this result is still true if $Y$, $X_i$ are not required
   to be Radon spaces but just general measure spaces as long as $Y =
       X_1 × X_2$ and $π_i : Y → X_i$ is the natural projection?

   In other words, given two measurable spaces $X_1$ and $X_2$ and a measure on the product measurable space $X_1 \times X_2$ , what are some necessary and/or sufficient conditions for the measure on $X_1 \times X_2$ to be the composition of some measure on $X_1$  and some transition measure  from $X_1$ to $X_2$?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: The first sentence of the question seems to be missing something, right?

Answer (score 3):

The disintegrations are really transition probabilities or proper, regular conditional probabilities. If we define a function $K:X\times\mathcal{Y}\to[0,1]$ by $K(x,B)=\mu_x(B)$, we get the corresponding transition probability.

1. I don't have a counterexample ready for the general case, but one can extend the result to $\sigma$-finite measure spaces, essentially by solving the problem separately for each cell of a countable, measurable partition as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/99022/21674).
2. No. Suppose you have an infinite product of the measurable spaces $(X_n,\mathcal{X}_n)$ and for each $n$ you have a measure $\mu_n$ on $\sigma(\mathcal{X}_1\times\ldots,\times\mathcal{X}_n)$ such that for all $B\in\sigma(\mathcal{X}_1\times\ldots,\times\mathcal{X}_{n-1})$ one has $\mu_{n-1}(B)=\mu_n(B\times X_n)$. If you could simply apply the disintegration theorem without further ado to product spaces, you could generate transition measures $K_n:X_{n+1}\times\sigma(\mathcal{X}_1\times\ldots,\times\mathcal{X})\to[0,1]$ that give you by the [Ionescu-Tulcea](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Ecshalizi/754/notes/lecture-03.pdf)-theorem a measure $\mu$ on the infinite product such that $\mu_n(B)=\mu(B\times X_{n+1}\times\ldots)$. But such an extension is in general not possible, as shown in an [example](http://gymarkiv.sdu.dk/MFM/kdvs/mfm%2020-29/mfm-25-4.pdf) by Andersen and Jessen in a 1948 paper called "On the introduction of measures in infinite product sets".

Comment: +1 Thanks! For part 2, I don't quite understand yet. My question is: given a measure on the product space, whether there exists one measure on each component space, such that the relation in terms of integrals in the disintegration theorem holds. Is your reply the other way around, i.e. given marginal measures, whether the product measure exists, s.t. the relation in terms of integrals in the disintegration theorem holds? (I have edited my part 2 in hope of being more clear.)

Comment: Even if you know the marginals, that doesn't give you the disintegrations connecting them. You asked for the latter. If one knows the first marginal and all conditional probabilities that allow you to construct the other "finite dimensional distributions", one can construct a process on the infinite product space. Since this is impossible by the mentioned example, there exists a product such that we cannot determine the probability of the second coordinate given the first.