# atom and measurable set

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

if $\Omega$ consists of a finite number atoms then $L^1(\Omega)$ is a finite dimension. why you can show this?

(An atom in $(X, \Omega, \mu)$   is a measurable set $E$ such that $\mu(E)>0$ and for every measurable subset $F\subset E$ 
either $\mu(F)=0$ or $\mu(F)=\mu(E)$.)

Comment: This might help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/866312/l1μ-is-finite-dimensional-if-it-is-reflexive

Comment: I dont really understand the question. Do you mean that $L^1$ is finite dimensional iff we can write $\Omega$ as a finite union of atoms?

Comment: this is in the question : The space $L^1(\Omega)$ is never reflexive except in the trivial case where$\Omega$ consists of a finite number of atoms—and then $L^1(\Omega)$ is finite-dimensional

Comment: The statement "if $\Omega$ has finite atoms" is not the same as saying that $\Omega$ is finite and every $\omega \in \Omega$ is an atom.

Comment: question is relation between $L^1(\Omega)$ and $\Omega$