# If $A$ is an atom then $\lambda (A) = 0$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am working on the following theorem:

**Theorem**

Let $(X,\mathscr{A})$ be a measure space with finite measure $\mu$, then $\mu$ can be written uniquely as the sum of a purely atomic measure and a non-atomic measure.
Let us call $\mathcal{N}$ is the union of the atoms with respect to $\mu$. We define
$$\lambda (A) = \mu(A\setminus \mathcal{N}) \hspace{2cm} \nu (A) = \mu(A\cap \mathcal{N})$$
Where $\lambda$ is non-atomic and $\nu$ is purely atomic, so we have tested that it can be decomposed into said sum, but I don't know how to show that it is unique, at first it occurs to me to give another $\mu_1 + \mu_2 = \mu$ sum representation where $ \mu_1 $ is purely atomic and $ \mu_2 $ is non-atomic, but I don't know what happens when evaluating an atom in a non-atomic measure, that is, if $A$ is an atom, does $ \mu_2 (A) = 0 $?

Can someone help me test the uniqueness?

Comment: Is $\mathcal{N}$ supposed to be the union of all atoms, rather than the set of all atoms?

Comment: No, $\mathcal{N}$  is the set of all atoms

Comment: Then how are $A \setminus \mathcal{N}$ and $A \cap \mathcal{N}$ defined?

Comment: Some discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/56327/43949).

Comment: True, it must be the union of the atoms